# How to return a key of an array from a function where the key is an arg?

Tags: php

I have made a simplified version of what I am trying to explain.

```
$array ('name' => 1, 'notname' => 1, 'anothername' => 2);

function a($name1, $name2){
  $total = $name1 + $name2;
  $winner = rand(0, $total);

  if ($winner > name2){
    $winner = $name1;
  } else {
    $winner = $name2;
  }

  return $winner;

}

echo a($array['name'], $array['notname']);
```

Instead of returning (and echoing) the winners number, I want to echo the name of the key for the winner.

I feel like I am making this way to hard.

Comment: The key, as opposed to the value.  I don't think I am doing a good job of explaining.

Comment: `'name'` is the key. `1` is the value.

Comment: Which one do you want to echo?

Comment: I want to echo the key, I do some math on the number value in the function and I want to pull whatever the answer was from the function out as the key.

Comment: The key is either `'name'` or `'notname'`, so the result of arithmetic isn't going to be either of those.

Comment: You are not passing the key only the value of that array element.  Not sure of the practicality, maybe if you explained what you are trying to accomplish in a broader sense.

Comment: I completely edited the code to hopefully be more specific.  Obviously I tried to make the question too generic.

Comment: Where does `odds2` come into play? You're also missing closing semi-colons for `$winner = $name1` and `$winner = $name2`

Comment: sorry that is out of my original code.  fixed thanks.

Comment: Now you're missing a `$` for `winner` in `winner = rand(0, $total);`

Comment: Better coming from me then from 20 others ;-) (*about missing chars.*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your function `a` is getting the numbers (array values) and not the array keys. You cannot get an array key from its value.

So you want:

```
$array ('name' => 1, 'notname' => 1, 'anothername' => 2);

function a($array, $name1, $name2){
  $total = $array[$name1] + $array[$name2];
  $winner = rand(0, $total);
  if ($winner > $array[$name2]){
    return $name1;
  else
    return $name2;
}

echo a($array, 'name', 'notname');
```

Comment: Ohh my goodness, thank you soo much!  I did such a bad job of explaining what I was trying to do at first.

I knew I was overthinking something.  Thanks again!

Comment: You can get an array key from its value. http://uk1.php.net/array_search - not necessarily the correct one if the values aren't unique.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you want, but it sounds to me like you're either trying to find a key based on its *position* within the array, or a key based on the corresponding *value*. There are a few functions that might be useful to you.

Start from `$example = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);`. The letters are the keys and the numbers are the values.

- [`array_keys`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) will return a new array containing the keys of the original array, in order. `array_keys($example)` will return `array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c')`. (You can use this to look up a key by position).
- [`array_flip`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) will return a new array with the keys exchanged with the values. `array_flip($example)` will return `array(1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c')`.
- [`array_search`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) will return the key of the first matching value. `array_search($example, 2)` will return `'b'`.

---

Edit: It sounds like you want to pluck out a key at random?
`array_keys($array)[rand(0, count($array) - 1)]` ??

---

Edit 2: Okay, I'm guessing that you mean the values of the array are probabilities of the corresponding name winning. (?)

Here is how I would write that function:

```
function selectWinner($players) {
    $select = mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax() * array_sum($players);
    $position = 0;
    foreach ($players as $name => $probability) {
        if (($position += $probability) >= $select) return $name;
    }
}
```

Now assume we have an array:

```
$players = array('Bob' => 1, 'Bert' => 1, 'Betty' => 2);
```

Calling `selectWinner($players)` will return Bob or Bert 25% of the time each, and will return Betty 50% of the time. The probabilities need not be integers.

For testing:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) @$counts[selectWinner($players)]++;
print_r($counts);
```

This outputs something like:

```
Array
(
    [Betty] => 4907
    [Bert] => 2560
    [Bob] => 2533
)
```

Comment: I can't use array_flip because some of the values are the same, looking into array_keys now.

Comment: No, I want to compare two values, have one be the "winner" and return the name of the key.  The array in reality has about 70 values.

Comment: Yes, That is helpful but not quite what I wanted to do.  I wanted to put Billy and Bob against each other and have it come out 50 / 50.  Then later put Billy and Bert against each other and have it come out 1/3 to 2/3.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're working with a more complicated problem in reality, I'm going to assume that

```
echo 'name';
```

won't do the trick.

A good way to get keys out of an array is with a foreach loop. For your example above,

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){ echo $key; }
```

would return

```
name notname
```

I don't know if that helps, but without more info its the best I can do.

Comment: right, this is essentially what I have, but I don't want to return not name.  I am trying to pull the value that was originally entered into the function.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an error in your array declaration, it should be:

```
$array('name' => 1, 'notname' => 2)
```

Second, you basically wrote a function that takes a variable as a parameter and then returns it. You are passing only the value to that function, the same as if you'd write echo a('something').

ALso, 'name' is the key of the first value in the array if you write it like this. I think you want to have 1 as the key, 'name' as the value, so you have to write it the other way around.

```
$array(1 => 'name)
```

Furthermore, I suggest taking another spin on CS basics :)

Comment: why would 'notname' not be able to hold a value of 1?

and I tried to make my question to generic (in hopes it would apply to other people) and instead confused everyone including myself.